# didn't work in ios4 UIToolBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios4

I have used UIToolBar in navigation controller. i have set the background image of UIToolbar using below code

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 4.9) {
                NSLog(@"IOS 5555555");
        //iOS 5
        if ([tools respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:)]) { 
            [tools setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }

    } else {
        //iOS 4
        NSLog(@"IOS 4444444");
        [tools insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:0]; 
    }
```

for ios5 it works fine but when i run my app in iOS 4 it set default value of toolbar. basically i need to set background image of UIToolBar.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that for iOs 4 you subclass  UIToolbar and overwrite drawRect method